# FBX Imported Mesh Looks Glossy when viewed from different angles

Tags: materials, import, .fbx

so I've imported this hands model i found on sketchfab and it look glossy when viewed from certain angles to the point where the material can't be seen , I've tried to remove the material and replace it with one of mine , still the same , so I'm assuming that it doesn't have something todo with the materials , wich left me confused , any idea how can i remove this effect from the mesh
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe try Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data? Or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks a lot !, it worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into *Object Data > Geometry Data >* and click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*. Some imported FBX files have split normals (normals that are used for shading) not correctly set.